# Aligment faults ignored on armv5te in qemu

Tags: assembly, exception, arm, qemu

I have a simple application compiled for arm that i run in QEMU. i'm interested in memory alignment faults when for instance i have instructions like:

```
ldr r3, =0xa0000001
ldr r4, [r3]
```

I have MMU enabled and Alignment check enabled:

```
mrc p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0
orr r0, r0, #0x3
mcr p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0
```

but my DATA ABORT exception handler (i've verified that it works in `gdb`) is not called when processor executes instructions like `ldr`s above. The emulated core is ARMv5TE. What could be the problem?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think it's just QEMU that doesn't bother with this kind of exceptions.

Comment: On real boards, I assure you'll be punished hard enough for that. :)

Comment: QEMU (don't know about ARM, but at least x86) is a good test emulator (ie test that the whole system works), but preforms poorly on some features not used in real life, like exceptions. Use another emulator (and in general, always use several emulators together with real machine to double-check that you system isn't written for one particular machine/emulator).

Comment: Where did you set the V bit and A bit? From the ARM manual, section B.2.7.6
"Therefore, in the following example (where A=1, V=0 initially), the LDR may or may not take a data abort
due to the unaligned transaction, but if an exception occurs, the vector used will be affected by the V bit:
Memory Order Model"

`MCR p15, r0, c1, c0, 0 ; clears the A bit and sets the V bit
LDR r2, [R3] ; unaligned load.`

Comment: Also read back the A bit to verify it is implemented. That may or may not be emulated.

Comment: @SilverCode V bit is 0 (Data abort handler is called correctly if a try to read at address not valid in my page table). A bit is set in `mcr` instruction (see `orr r0, r0, #0x3`). I also tried to read again register after write and A bit is correctly set. What do you think about the sentece in section B2.7.6: "Any change of state held in CP15 registers involv
ed in the triggering of an exception is not yet
guaranteed to be visible while any change involved
with the processing of the exception itself (once
it is determined that the exception is being taken) is guaranteed to take effect."? Thank

Comment: Don't you love that kind of non-deterministic wording? I took it to mean anything in the pipeline that had already been fetched would not cause the exception. Stuff the pipe with a few nop instructions perhaps, and try? Also this may be one of those corner cases in emulation that was never fully fleshed out.

Comment: BTW you should pick up a cheap ARM board, a Raspberry PI or some such, and see what really happens. I understand that working with QEMU is nice an easy though, but once you get your workflow down you will find working with real hardware much more rewarding. Grab a JTAG too. 
I use an olimex + openocd more than the multi thousand dollar lauterbach and ARM ICE available to me - simplicity is king.